# disable email notifications to jomsocial users

Tags: email, notifications, joomla3.0, jomsocial

L.S.,
I have jomsocial 3.0.2 running on my Jommla 3.1.5 website. Though I have disabled system emails in the configuration, aswell as all other email notifications (except for email notification for removal of the profile) on the administrative side, my users keep getting notification emails. My mail queue is filled with notifications that are sent out with the set up Cron job. 
How do I disable email notifications? I use Jomsocial for a project in which school children get to interact with each other, but since all the kids are registered under their parents'email addresses I don't want to spam those addresses with notifications. I want them to have the option to receive email notifications, instead of receiving unwanted messages by my site. The parents are aware of how to disable the email notifications from the user's side, but I want to save them the trouble by disabling all email notifications. On site notifications can be sent to all users.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in `/controllers/register.php`

add a comment as below

```
//$this->_sendEMail('registration_uncomplete', $tmpUser, $password); 
$var = NULL;
```

You can disable any other email using the same method. Just find out which line sends the email and comment it out.